# NestJS CQRS module: Event handlers not called when I register a EventPublisher

Tags: nestjs, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm using CQRS module of NestJS.

I just want to be sure about something. I've created a custom `EventPublisher` that has a publish method. This method just publish the event in my database.

```
@Module({
  imports: [CqrsModule, DatabaseModule],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [
    TransactionsService,
    AccountRepository,
    MongooseEventStore,
    ...CommandHandlers,
    ...EventHandlers,
    ...accountsProvider,
  ],
})
export class UsersModule implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(
    private readonly eventBus: EventBus,
    private readonly eventStore: MongooseEventStore,
  ) {}

  onModuleInit() {
    this.eventBus.publisher = this.eventStore;
  }
}
```

Now, event handlers aren't called anymore, even if I registered them by doing

```
this.eventBus.register(EventHandlers)
```

My EventHandler is only this:

```
@EventsHandler(TransactionCreatedEvent)
export class TransactionCreatedHandler
  implements IEventHandler<TransactionCreatedEvent>
{
  handle({ payload }: TransactionCreatedEvent) {
    Logger.log(payload);
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can publish event in event store, and if success, forward the event to others handlers ? I'll need this functionality to build my MaterializeView.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. If you set a custom `Publisher` for the `EventBus`, you'll no longer use the publish of the default InMemoryPubSub publisher that use internally the `EventBus` `subject$` to bridge events to handlers.

In my case, I do Event Sourcing, I want to save event in my database before dispatch them to handlers, so I save them THEN I dispatch them to the `EventBus` `subject$` so it can forward it to handlers:

```
export class EventStore implements IEventPublisher, IMessageSource {
  subject$: Subject<any>;
  constructor(
    @Inject(ACCOUNT_MODEL_NAME)
    private readonly accountModel: Model<AccountDocument>,
  ) {}
  bridgeEventsTo<T extends IEvent>(subject$: Subject<T>) {
    this.subject$ = subject$;
  }

  publish(event: any) {
    this.accountModel.create({
      payload: event.payload,
      uid: event.uid,
      event_type: event.event,
    });
    this.subject$.next(event);
  }
}
```

You can bridge them in your module init:

```
export class UsersModule implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(
    private readonly eventBus: EventBus,
    private readonly eventStore: EventStore,
  ) {}

  onModuleInit() {
    this.eventStore.bridgeEventsTo(this.eventBus.subject$);
    this.eventBus.publisher = this.eventStore;
  }
```